# Unable to connect to db using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing a site using PHP Zend Framework. Previously it works fine. I added a .htaccess file in the root folder; now my site is not working. I get the following error. I delete that .htaccess file, still face same issue.

Errors :

> (Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'reiceps'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/sdiphp.com/subdomains/caialarecipes/httpdocs/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:145
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/sdiphp.com/subdomains/caialarecipes/httpdocs/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96):

Answer (score 4):

That's not an htaccess problem it looks like your mysql credentials have been rejected. probably because you misspelled **recipes** `'reiceps'@'localhost'` at least that's what the error indicates.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,now i corrected my file its working fine